# Фиксированный ul

Tags: html, css

Здравствуйте! На сайте есть конструкция что-то типа:

```
<ul>
  <li>...</li>
  <li>
     <ol>
        <li>...</li>
        <li>...</li>
     </ol>
</ul>
```

Выглядит так: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сейчас css свойства такие:

```
ul li
     {
        display: inline-block;
     }

ol li
     {
        display: block;
     }
```

Проблема в том что когда мы разворачиваем список(т.е. `ol>li`) происходит вот это:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать так чтобы пункты меню (`Ищу`, `Кому`, `Метро`) оставались на своих местах при раскрытии какого-либо списка, а разворачивалось только их содержимое

Answer (score 1):

Используйте абсолютное позиционирование, вот как пример:

```css
*{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
ul, ol{
  list-style: none;
}

ul>li{
  float: left;
  padding: .5rem 1rem;
  position: relative;
  background-color: skyblue;
  color: white;
}

ol{
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
}

ol>li {
  padding: .5rem 1rem;
  background-color: grey;
  color: white;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>первый</li>
  <li>второй
     <ol>
        <li>123</li>
        <li>456 пример днинного li</li>
     </ol>
</ul>
```

Comment: На тот что в заданном вопросе такая структура, не стоит умничать и грубить.

Comment: В вопросе использовался ol, человек может использовать нумерацию списка и ему так удобнее, вопрос был задан за формирование списка а не правильность написания кода. Как следствие, я предлагаю решения привязываясь к существующему коду. Возможно у него формируется так список и он его лишь только стилизует, как вам такой вариант?  ps.  рассматриваю  `на кой` как не дописанное ругательство вот и не рекомендую ео использовать. На ты я с вами тоже не переходил.

Comment: @Air, в данном случае @Ruslan Semenov абсолютно прав. Мне желательно придерживаться такой структуры (`ul`, `ol`), и менять только стили. И в примере кода я указал это не зря! Так если вы хорошо понимаете, может подскажите решение сами?)

Comment: @Air, к слову, это не мой код, а часть кода движка WordPress, мне лишь нужное кое-что поменять в нем)